# Need help changing speed, direction and spawn time of SKSpriteNode called in didMoveToView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

sorry for the wall of text, I just wanted to give a good explanation of how my game is set up so you can understand my problem better. 
I have a few questions about the game that I am currently making using swift.

I am making a game where a player has to dodge enemies. The player is an SKSpriteNode image which gets it’s physics body and is added to the scene here:

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: player.size.width/2)
        player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
        player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
        player.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        addChild(player)
    }
```

This implementation seems to work great, I have collision working between the Player and Enemy.

The enemies are initialised as SkSpriteNodes too:

```
func addEnemy() {
        let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: “enemy”)
        enemy.name = “enemy”
        enemy.position = CGPoint(x: size.height/2, y: size.width/2)
        self.addChild(enemy)
        enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemy.size.width/2.75)
        enemy.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
        enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
        enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None 

// code for making the enemies move here (including speed)
        }
        enemy.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveAction,removeAction]))
    }
```

and are constantly spawned every 0.7 seconds in didMoveToView(view: SKView) like this:

```
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(addEnemy),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(0.7)
            ])
        ))
```

So my question is as follows. Is this the most appropriate way to do what I am trying to achieve? That is; spawning multiple different types of enemies constantly at different intervals?

I am struggling to figure out how I could (for example), make the enemy start spawning only after 10 seconds has passed, or how I could change the direction of the enemies with the press of a UIButton on screen? It seems since they are all called and created when the view loads, I can’t be making constant changes to things like direction, speed etc.

What is a better way of doing this, or how can I do what I need?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is use the update method instead of using a repeating SKAction.

In update you calculate how much time has passed using currentTime and then decided on if you should spawn an enemy or not. This also gives you a chance to spawn an enemy any way you want based on the current state of your game.

As far as the button. It really depends on your game, but most games have some sort of count down or requires some sort of user interaction before game play begins.

**EDIT**

My swift is a bit rusty but it would be something like this...

```
var lastUpdateTime = 0.0;
var spawnTimer = 0.0;
var nextSpawnTime = 10.0;

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (lastUpdateTime == 0.0)
    {
        lastUpdateTime = currentTime
        return
    }

    spawnTimer += currentTime-lastUpdateTime

    //Do any other update logic here

    if (spawnTimer >= nextSpawnTime)
    {
        spawnTimer = 0.0
        spawn()
    }

    lastUpdateTime = currentTime

}

func spawn ()
{
    //spawn and change nextSpawnTime if you wish
    println("spawn")

}
```

Hopefully that helps and makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is helpful. I'm having trouble using currentTime to call a function every 10 seconds in update. Could you help me out with that?

Comment: Whenever I try and spawn items in update they just continuously spawn every call of update which is very fast. Can you help with this ^^

Comment: Amazing I can't thank you enough, worked perfectly! :)